# Laravel 5.0, env() returns null during concurrent requests

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The problem is that when I try to get a config variable using `env('setting')` or `\Config::get('setting')`, sometimes it returns null.

For the testing reason I created a simple route:

```php
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $env = env('SETTING');
    if (!$env) {
        \Log::warning('test', [$env]);
    }
});
```

Then I used apache benchmark. And the results were like this:

- Calling only one request at a time (`ab -n 100 -c 1 http://localhost/test`) there were no problem, no records in the log file
- Calling with 10 concurrent requests (`ab -n 100 -c 10 http://localhost/test`) I got about 20 lines like this: `[2015-06-22 14:19:48] local.WARNING: test [null]`

Does anybody know, what can be the problem? Is there something missing in my configuration or in php settings?

Comment: `setting` or `SETTING` variable exists in env file ?

Comment: Yes, sure. If it wasn't then I would get all 100 warnings in the log file even with non-concurrent requests.

Comment: well, in that case, first you need to check your current env set or not i mean 'Local' or `Production`, and then try `dd($_ENV)` and final try  `$environment = app()->environment();`

Comment: I should probably clarify that this functionality usually works fine, `env()` gives me correct values, `app()->environment()` gives me `'local'` and `$_ENV` contains all the settings from `.env` file. The problem only happens during concurrent requests. For example, `app()->environment()` gave me `'production'` 26 times out of 1000 requests with the concurrency of 20; without concurrency all of them are only `'local'`, without exception. Interestingly that variable `$_ENV` was empty in 830 requests out of 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know bug in dotenv package - see the discussion here
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8191

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me as well. My workaround is in your `config/app.php` you have to add this:

```
'setting' => env('SETTING'),
```

Then when you want to get the setting config you have to do this:

```
$env = config('app.setting');
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. All `config('app.setting')`, `\Config::get('app.setting')` and `env('SETTING')` produce the same result. Well, `config()` might be producing empty content slightly less often, than `env()`, but it does anyway.

Comment: Did you try this? It still returns null during concurrent requests? This works for me though

Comment: Of course, I did. I even made some statistics which gives me roughtly:
20 fails of 1000 for `config()`, 30 for `\Config::get()` and 110 for `env()`
So, using `config()` does work better, I don't know why, but still, it fails.

Comment: This doesn't work! I am using Laravel 9 and all the solutions mentioned here don't work!