# Laravel: How to check if user is admin?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make the user an administrator who at the entrance to the site conditions are checked == user login , if so then give the right to remove or edit product. This is my code so far:

```
@if(Auth::check())
   <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Edite</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Remove</a></p>
@endif
```

How equate `Auth::check()` with my login?

Comment: Auth::check() will only check if they are logged in. How are you storing who is an admin? Is jt just another column in your users table?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Is your question: "How do I check if the connected user is an Admin instead of only using Auth::check() method?" If this is the question, likes James is saying, do you have any roles in you database?

Comment: How do you distinguish common users from admin users?

Answer (score 32):

First of all you need to create the role table that contain the roles details. (I'm assuming Each user may have multiple roles not only Administrator)

Roles Table:

```
    Schema::create('role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
    });
```

Then

user_role Table:

```
Schema::create('user_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('role_id')
        ->references('id')->on('roles');
});
```

Create Role model:

```
php artisan make:model Role
```

Afterwards add the roles relationship to the user model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_role');
    }
}
```

To check if user has Administrator role you can do something like:

```
@if($user->roles()->where('name', 'Administrator')->exists())
enter code here
@endif
```

Or instead of doing this statement you can put as function in the User model as below:

```
public function isAdministrator() {
   return $this->roles()->where('name', 'Administrator')->exists();
}
```

Then in your model you can call it:

```
@if(Auth::user()->isAdministrator())
enter code here
@endif
```

**Other possibility (1 - 1) Relation**

First add is_admin column in your migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(0);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Then you can check:

```
@if($user->is_admin)

@endif
```

Comment: well done, but i think thats complicated as a start for him , but thats how it should be done

Comment: The ideal solution and it's  a good introduction for rbac/acl systems

Comment: This is a great solution and works fine. You can extend this to allow fine grained authorization using permissions. And probably associate permissions with each role or even overlapping permissions on different roles. But for a start this is OK

Comment: Just a note, with Laravel 8 when creating ('user_role') , the column  $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();  must be created as bigInteger not integer or it will throw a foreign key constraint incompatibility.

$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();

Comment: Another suggestion I may add is to name the role table in plural: 'roles', therefore the table would be created like this: Schema::create('roles'     ...) and the foreign key at user_roles would be assigned like this: $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');

Comment: @toolnin feel free to update my answer ;)

Comment: @devnull I did not want to edit your answer because it works, nothing wrong with it. I have added a separate answer for Laravel 7 and 8. :)

Answer (score 14):

Standard way is to do what xdevnull mentioned. But for small projects you can do something like this:

```
If(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
  dd("you are admin") ;
}
```

And in your User model create a method isAdmin()

```
function isAdmin() {
  $admin_emails = config('settings.admin_emails');
  if(in_array($this->email, $admin_emails)  return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Of course you need to create a config file called settings in your app/config folder.

And put this in settings.php

```
<?php
return ['admin_emails' => explode(', ',  env('ADMIN_EMAILS'));]
```

And finally in your .env file add this:
    ADMIN_EMAILS=user1@example.com,user2@example.com

*Add as much emails as you want spayed by commas*.

Now if logged in user has email as user1@example.com or user2@example.com then she is Admin.

*Also notice I have added admin emails in env file so that admins can be changed depending on the environment. In development usually developer is the admin while in production somebody else (client?) is the admin.*

**P.S. don't forget to run `php artisan config:cache` after creating your settings.php file**

Comment: Undefined variable: admin_email (View: D:\OpenServer\domains\sportgoods\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Comment: Edit: change $admin_email to $this->email in isAdmin() method

Comment: function isAdmin() {
        $admin_emails = config('settings.admin_emails');
        if(in_array($this->email, $admin_emails)) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }                                                                                                                   Like this?

Comment: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given (View: D:\OpenServer\domains\sportgoods\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Comment: So you aren't getting the values from your config. have you added the values properly and done php artisan config:cache?

Comment: I have create file "settings" in config/settings.php and inside I have written this code <?php return explode(', ', env('ADMIN_EMAILS')); ?>. Then I have written in the Model this code function isAdmin() {
        $admin_emails = config('settings.admin_emails');
        if(in_array($this->email, $admin_emails))  return true;
        else return false;
    }                                                                                                                      Now laravel is writing - in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given (View:index.blade.php)

Comment: I am asking have you run php artisan config:cache?

Comment: Yes, I have ran php artisan config:cache

Comment: restart your server then. I am sure your env values are returning null.

Comment: Also I hope you have added admin emails in your env file.

Comment: I have already done restart, my env file http://s05.radikal.ru/i178/1605/39/9623a200752d.png

Comment: Man! don't know seem like it's a known issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/32282783/3476207 :(

Comment: I would suggest if he go through Achraf Khouadja answer. seems more clear for what he's trying to achieve, anyways i'll update my answer to make the relationship 1 - 1

Comment: Shit! I have updated the answer. I missed 'admin_emails' key in settings file. @HeartOfprogrammer Check the edited answer.

Comment: One moment, I didn't understand that where I must put this code                  return ['admin_emails' => explode(', ',  env('ADMIN_EMAILS'))];  ?

Comment: In your settings.php file

Comment: This settings.php file I must create in this folder "config"? I'm sorry, I don't know English well

Comment: Yes. You have already created it right? Just replace the content from this answer.

Comment: So everything right and I had, But laravel show me error - in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given (View: D:\OpenServer\domains\sportgoods\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Comment: Done config cache again? whenever you make changes to any file in config folder do php artisan config:cache

Comment: My html + php file. <div class="caption">
<h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor nobis perspiciatis provident quasi recusandae rerum voluptatem.</p>
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin())
 <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Edit</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Remove</a></p>
@endif
</div>                                                                                                                          Is it Right?

Comment: After php artisan config:cache, laravel show new problem -  strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: D:\OpenServer\domains\sportgoods\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Comment: discuss here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111338/laravel-how-to-check-if-user-is-admin

Comment: @HeartOfprogrammer That's because $admin_emails is an array, you can change it as below ```if(in_array(strtolower($this->email), array_map(function($element) { return strtolower($element); },$admin_emails))  return true;```

Comment: No that's not the problem we are using in_array http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php.
@HeartOfprogrammer can you check your laravel.log file and see on which line you are getting error.

Comment: @Abhishek check your code ```strtolower($admin_emails)``` i$admin_emails is typeof array not string

Comment: WTF! How I got strtolower in my code :D Thanks @xdevnull.

Comment: @HeartOfprogrammer please remove strtolwer in both places.

Comment: @Abhishek Well strtolower is required just in case if he type string in different way. ```aB@example.com is not equal Ab@example.com``` in your case

Comment: @xdevnull emails are always case sensitive

Comment: @Abhishek I think you're missing some PHP basics. Check this out http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf39c5401e9844a877e5117bfb70c2e16de9c7fa

Comment: @xdevnull there is nothing in "missing php basics"  if I assume that emails are and should always be case sensitive.

Comment: It's working in my local now. Have you removed strtolower()  in isAdmin method? What error are you getting now?

Comment: Can you send me correct code without strtolower, I haven't experienced developer.

Comment: This answer is your code without strtolower. Where you expect me to send the working code? Try implementing it check logs and tell me what error you are getting. I can't give you complete code.

Answer (score 2):

here u go

```
  @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == "admin")

  @endif
```

you have to role attribute to your database and it should contain admin or anything else (you can use bolean attribute too)

Answer (score 2):

```
@if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role->id==1)  
          return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
  @endif
```

Comment: https://github.com/mdazizurrahman/DownLoadThemeUpdate-version-3rd
 follow  this link

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel 7 or 8
(this is an update to devnull's answer which I think is the best approach)

Inside your project folder create the following models:

```
$ php artisan make:model Role -m
$ php artisan make:model role_user -m
```

This will generate the files:

- create_roles_table.php
- create_role_users_table.php
- Models/Role.php
- Models/role_user.php

Add the following fields to the create_roles_table.php Schema:

```
$table->id();
$table->string('name');
$table->timestamps();
```

Add the following fields and foreign key relationships to the create_role_users_table.php Schema and ALSO change the table name by removing the letter 's' added by Laravel on 'role_users' to be 'role_user':

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // having $table->id(); here is optional
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
    });
}
```

Also rename 'role_users' to 'role_user' in the down() method Schema:

```
Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
```

Run your migrations:

```
$ php artisan migrate
```

Add some data to your roles table depending on your needs, for example:

```
id: 1 | name: "Admin"
id: 2 | name: "Moderator"
id: 3 | name: "Basic"
```

Go to the User Model and create the function that handles the relationship between Role and User:

```
public function roles() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

This allows the user to have multiple Roles (a User can be an Admin, a Moderator and a Basic user as well).

Also inside the User Model create a function or multiple functions to check the User Roles depending on your project needs:

```
public function isAdmin() {
   return $this->roles()->where('name', 'Admin')->exists();
}

public function isModerator() {
   return $this->roles()->where('name', 'Moderator')->exists();
}
```

etc...

Make sure that there is at least one user in the user table. Now you can add values to the role_user table.

From blade you can check if a user is an Admin or whatever roles you created, calling the functions we created inside the User Model:

```
@guest

   You are not logged in

@else

   You are logged in!

   @if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
     You are an Admin, showing Admin options...
   @endif

   @if(Auth::user()->isModerator())
     You are a Moderator, showing Moderator options
   @endif

@endguest
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to write below code in **your** UsersTable migration :

```
 $table->enum('role',  ['user', 'manager', 'admin'])->default('user');
```

**in the second step** Run migration ,
then define your gates in `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php` like this :

```
namespace App\Providers;
  
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
  
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
            
    ];
  
    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
   
        /* define a admin user role */
        Gate::define('isAdmin', function($user) {
           return $user->role == 'admin';
        });
       
        /* define a manager user role */
        Gate::define('isManager', function($user) {
            return $user->role == 'manager';
        });
      
        /* define a user role */
        Gate::define('isUser', function($user) {
            return $user->role == 'user';
        });
    }
}
```

now you can use `isAdmin` , `isUser` , `isManager` methods in your view.blade files

like this

```
  @can('isAdmin')
      <div class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
          You have Admin Access
      </div>
  @elsecan('isManager')
      <div class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
          You have Manager Access
      </div>
  @else
      <div class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
          You have User Access
      </div>
  @endcan
```

and after all there are many other ways to do it;
you can refer to this link for more details
[my source](https://www.codecheef.org/article/laravel-gate-and-policy-example-from-scratch)

Answer (score 1):

Something that works for me.

In controller:

```
$user = Auth::user()->role()->where('name', 'admin')->exists();
return view('user.index', compact('user'));
```

In view:

```
@if($user)
    //enter code here ...
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a role column attached to your users table then do this

In the User model in the User.php file add this

```
public function isAdmin() {
  return $this->role == 'admin'
}

public function isCouple() {
  return $this->role == 'couple'  
}

public function isServiceProvider() {
  return $this->role == 'serviceProvider'
}
```

In your blade use this

```
@if(Auth::user()->isServiceProvider())
 //am a service provider
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.5. this worked for me :

```
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role['name'] == "admin")
   // You are an Admin                    
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@auth
    @if(auth()->user()->role_id == 1)
       i am Admin
    @endif
@endauth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@auth   

     @php 
     $user= auth::user()->id;
     @endphp 
    
    <div>{{$user}}</div> 

@else
 
    Auth is not login

@endauth
```

you can also get the user detail in view page by this mathod.

Answer (score 0):

After saw many answers that talks about ***isAdmin*** method in User class,
I have to say that **there's no need to create such method.**

There is already the method **HasRole**

You can call this from *artisan tinker* from command line, just to see it *before writing code*:

```
php artisan tinker
```

Check if the user with id 1 has role 'user';

```
User::find(1)->hasRole('user');
```

Check if the user with id 1 has role 'admin';

```
User::find(1)->hasRole('admin');
```

The same way while coding for example in app.blade template:

```
@if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
   <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Edite</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Remove</a></p>

@endif
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### 1.First step - create database column for user type

First, you need to add to your **users** table a column for the user type - let's name it **"user_type_id"** *(I prefer to work with IDs because it is faster and well-organized)*

In **migrations folder** find your user table migration file and in the up() method you should have something like this:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('user_type_id')->default(config('app.default_admin_type_id'));
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This line is important to be added: (the user_type_id)

```
$table->integer('user_type_id')->default(config('app.default_admin_type_id'));
```

In the folder and file **config/app.php** I created a constant named **default_admin_type_id** equal to -1. *(you can set it to whatever number you want)* **I use this constant to update the value into one place and then check for it wherever I want.**

```
'default_admin_type_id' => -1,
```

---

### 2.Second - edit AuthServiceProvider.php

Go to the file **/app/Http/Providers** and open **AuthServiceProvider.php** file and edit the **boot()** method like this:

```
public function boot()
    {
        Gate::define("Admin",function(User $user){
            
            if($user->user_type_id == config('app.default_admin_type_id')){
               return true;
            }
            return false; 
        });

        $this->registerPolicies(); 
    }
```

The idea here is that you create (define) a gate with the name "Admin" and you check if the user_type_id is equal to the default_admi_type_id stored in the app.php config files.

---

### 3.Use the "Admin" gate in classes

You can check if a user is of the desired type like this:

```
public function delete()
{
    if (Gate::allows('Admin')) {
        dd('Admin allowed');
    } else {
        dd('You are not Admin');
    }
}
```

---

### 4.Use the "Admin" gate in blade views

You can check if a user is of the desired type like this:

```
    @can('Admin')
<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Edite</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Remove</a></p>
    @endcan
```

That's all!

Cheers,
Hope to help other scenarios as well.