# Check if user is admin in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to check if the user is admin or not.

`User table`

```
id | role_id | name
1  | 3       | test
```

`Role table`

```
id | role     
1  | user     
2  | employee 
3  | admin
```

`User model`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'gender', 'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}

public function isAdmin() {
   return $this->roles()->where('role', 'user')->exists();
}
```

}

`Role model`

```
class Role extends Model
{
 //
}
```

`Blade template`

```
 @if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
     user is admin
 @endif
```

I cant find the answer what I have to add in the `function isAdmin` nothing works. Now i get the error Base table or view not found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: How to check if user is admin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093523/laravel-how-to-check-if-user-is-admin)

Comment: Base table or view not found. This error is when you try to access table which name is not plural that is there is no `s` at the end.

Comment: @BorisShchegolev I tried that and it is not working.

Comment: @Iftikharuddin so I have to change `public function roles` to `role` ? I did that and now it says Call to undefined method

Comment: nah Model name should be singular, db table name should be plural. If you have that then this is not the problem, double check that.

Comment: Hmm well it is correct.

Comment: @JustinTime for `Base table or view not found` error, add the ` protected $table = 'user';` in user Model and ` protected $table = 'role';` in Role model. Reference -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#defining-models

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'gender', 'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}

public function isAdmin() {
   if($this->role->name == 'admin'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This works! is it possible to do it like this? `public function is($roleName) {
       if($this->role->name == $roleName){
            return true;
        }
        return false;` 
    }

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Yes that is possible but from where you will pass role?

Comment: But I dont want to write for every role a function. Is it possible to make one function for all?

Comment: What of multiple roles?

Comment: `return $this->role->name == 'admin'` a one liner.